# Decouple Angular modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modularity, decoupling

I have a search web app made with AngularJS, which includes two angular modules: the `search-keyword-input` module and the `search-action` module.

The first `search-keyword-input` module has suggest functionality, form validation functionality, and so on. The `search-action` module's functionality is requesting data and showing sortable results in a table. So each module has its own controller and directive.

Here's the problem: the reason I modularize is, I want modules that could be reused and decoupled. But in this app, the keyword model value in the `search-keyword-input` module has to be passed into the search action module (the `search-action` module has to know what keyword to use to perform the search). So how can I pass the value between modules? How can they communicate without being coupled?

I have figured out a way like adding a parent controller and global $scope value:

```
<div ng-controller="globalController">
    <div ng-controller="keywordController"></div>
    <div ng-controller="searchController"></div>
</div>
```

So the `search-keyword` module could set the keyword value on the `globalController`'s `$scope` and the `search-action` controller could also obtain that keyword value from the `globalController`. But I think this makes the modularization meaningless because they are coupled together. What else can I do?

Comment: aren't these *already* coupled, just by virtue of the fact that one is reliant upon the other?  Does the `search` module already have some way to search without a `keyword`?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a custom service that can be shared by both controllers, and also used individually, rather than polluting the parent scope.